# Reproject layer in QGIS3 from consol

Tags: qgis-3

I had some problems with the processing alg `reprojectlayer` in QGIS3. Earlier in QGIS2.18 I used following command:

> processing.run('qgis:reprojectlayer', 'path_AND_filename_to_org_file','EGSG: 4326', 'path_to_new_file')

But it doesn't work in QGIS3

Answer (score 1):

The solution in QGIS3 is:

```
>>> parameter = {'INPUT': 'Path_to_input', 'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:4326',
                 'OUTPUT': 'path_to_output'}

>>> processing.run('qgis:reprojectlayer', parameter)
```